# Power Automate - display pdf content from trigger email attachment in body of sent email

Tags: pdf, gmail, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that monitors an email inbox for certain criteria and forwards incoming emails to other defined email addresses when that criteria is met. The email will always have a pdf attachment, and this flow successfully forwards the pdf attachment.

In addition to forwarding the attachment, I need to be able to display the pdf content in the body of the forwarded email, as if it's printed out.

I've tried various things, but so far I have not successfully rendered the image/printout. Is this possible? This is the flow I have, and the last thing I tried for the body to print the image.[PDF print to body of email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKpv1.png)

Much appreciated!

Comment: The ability to embed files this way has long been removed by email clients (think of the security implications). The best you can do is convert the PDF to an image then add that to your email body. Do a search on "PDF to image Power Automate" to find a few Premium connectors.